# How to have an image porportional to screen inside of a scrollview?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can get this to work fine if I set a pixel height on my image, but I'm trying to get it to be 40% of the scrollview height, and have the text be able to expand off screen and scroll up(and image scroll out of the way and I'm having trouble with this.

The left is how it would load, and the right is how it would scroll up. The black frame is the device screen.

I tried using a grid with two rows ( *4 and *6) but when the orange area of text is large enough to go off the screen, the image ends up filling 40% of the height including the area off the screen and not 40% of the visible screen area

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could pass the Height of the screen into the constructor of you `ContentPage` and then you would be able to set the image row's height to 40 % of the screen height and allow the text to take up the rest of the space. You would then also need to subscribe to the `SizeChanged` events in order to change the row height when the orientation changes. Or you could set your `Image` to 40% of the screen height and set the image row height to by `Auto`.

Comment: @hvaughan3 This is how I ended up doing it over the weekend, but my understanding was it was bad practice to use screen pixel height to lay things out, so was I trying to avoid it. Seems like there would be a way to do this build into xamarin.forms rather than set the height from ios/android project and use that around.

Comment: Actually I do not use screen pixel height. I meant that you can use the `ContentPage.Height` and `ContentPage.Width` properties in the Xamarin Forms project. Those properties do not get filled in with values until after the page's Constructor has run, so that is why you would need to collect those values from a previous `ContentPage` and pass them into your image text scrolling `ContentPage` through it's constructor. Let me know if a code example would help.